# i want to upload image in draft js editor. image completely uploaded in server but draft js can not store url in img block

Tags: node.js, reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg, draft-js-plugins

I want to upload Image in draft js Editor. when i upload image in server then it successfully uploaded in server and get back imageurl. i want to save this url in `<img src="" />` src attribute in draft js but it is not work when i InsertImage function call with url then it show error

`editorState.getCurrentContent is not a function`

if you what is my problem then please tell me

```
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import { convertToHTML } from 'draft-convert';


    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
        EditorState.createEmpty()
    );
    const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);


    const onEditorStateChange = (newEditorState) => {
        setEditorState(newEditorState);
    };



    const blockToHTML = (block) => {
        if (block.type === 'code') {
            return <code>{block.text}</code>;
        }
        // Handle other block types if needed
    };

    const options = {
        blockToHTML,
    };

    // ...

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();

        const html = convertToHTML(options)(editorState.getCurrentContent());
        setConvertedContent(html);

    }, [editorState]);

    const handleImageUpload = async (file) => {
  


        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', file);
                axios.post('/saveimg', formData)
                    
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log('Uploaded Data', data);
                        const { imageLink } = data.data;
                        console.log(imageLink);
                        resolve({ data: { link: imageLink } });
                        insertImage(imageLink);
                    });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    };



    const insertImage = (url) => {
        const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
        const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
          'IMAGE',
          'IMMUTABLE',
          { src: url }
        );
        const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
        const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, {
          currentContent: contentStateWithEntity,
        });
      
        const newContentState = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(
          newEditorState.getCurrentContent(),
          entityKey,
          ' '
        );
      
        const newEditorStateWithImage = EditorState.createWithContent(
          newContentState
        );
        setEditorState(newEditorStateWithImage);
      };
      



 <div class="container-scroller">
                                 <div style={{ border: '1px solid #CCCCCC', minHeight: 300, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
                                                        <Editor
                                                            editorState={editorState}
                                                            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
                                                            toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                                                            wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                                                            editorClassName="editorClassName"
                                                            toolbar={{
                                                               
                                                                image: {
                                                                    uploadCallback: handleImageUpload,
                                                                    alt: { present: true, mandatory: false },
                                                                },
                                                            }}
                                                           
                                                        />
                                                    </div>


            </div>
```